# Is there any front end project used to view apache spark result?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark SQL to do some analysis. 
I`m wondering is there any Front end projects can be used to view the result? I mean the analysis result not the job successful / faile status

For example, granafa， kibana, etc..

Regards
Mingwei

Comment: Which result? "Job succeeded/failed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean visualization of your results (like the ones you've mentioned) you might be interested in [Apache Zeppellin](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/). It's more like [IPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) so you can write your code there and visualize results.

Otherwise you'd have to tell us what is your storage format and where are you storing your results - maybe there are some visualization tools for it.

Actually if you store your results of Spark jobs in ElasticSearch you can use Kibana with it.

Otherwise, I don't think there is anything. The difference between what you are referring to (openTSDB and Elasticsearch) and Spark is that the latter is not a datastore.

Comment: I`m looking for something to spark like the granfa to openTSDB, kibana to Elasticsearch.  Thanks for your answer. It seems exactly what I need.  Let me check the docs.

Comment: @KramerLi well Spark isn't a data store like openTSDB and Elasticsearch so writing a similar visualization tool might not be very useful, what would be your usecase?

Comment: Yes you are right. I will save the calculation result in somewhere else. So I should focus on how to view data from those storage. Thanks for high lightening me